# Convert UIView in to EAGLView?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to create custom EAGLView class, how do it? Actual problem is that i m developing game application in cocos2D and i want to capture some video of screen of gameplay. So i importing one UIView class from [this](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673) link

But given link only capture video of UIView and my application master view is EAGLView so that i didn't get success to capture my gameplay video. How i will do that using those class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link on how to programmatically capture a screenshot of your game: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html)

Edit: This will only take a snapshot(screen shot) of the active `glView` Context not any UIKit elements